# Cursors in Database compared to JDBC cursors and SQLJ cursors

Tags: jdbc, cursor, db2, sqlj

Could someone briefly compare and contrast the use of cursors in SQL procedures with their use
in

1. JDBC
2. SQLJ

Answer (score 0):

Queries as static when using SQLj. Instead, they are dynamic when using JDBC, this means that query compilation and access plan is calculated when the query is executed. In SQLj, these steps are done at compilation time, leaving the execution only to access the data.